# JOIN Two Table with Latest foreign key Entry

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

- I have a device table (A) and another table (B) with the device details.
- Table B has multiple entries for each device id of Table A.
- I need to fetch all the Devices from Table A along with its latest entry from Table B.

Table A:

```
+----+--------+---------+
| id1| name   | Details |
+----+--------+---------+
| 1  | name1  | text1   |
| 2  | name2  | text2   |
| 3  | name3  | text3   |
| 4  | name4  | text4   |
+----+--------+---------+
```

Table B:

```
+----+-------------+---------+
| id2|  device_id  | battery |
+----+-------------+---------+
| 1  | 1           | 20%     |
| 2  | 1           | 40%     |
| 3  | 1           | 30%     |
| 4  | 2           | 15%     |
| 5  | 2           | 75%     |
| 6  | 3           | 90%     |
+----+-------------+---------+
```

Expected Result:

```
+----+-------------+---------+
| id1|  device_id  | battery |
+----+-------------+---------+
| 1  | 1           | 30%     |
| 2  | 2           | 75%     |
| 3  | 3           | 90%     |
| 4  | NULL        | NULL    |
+----+-------------+---------+
```

Comment: I have added the `greatest-n-per-group` tag, which should match your usecase. Try reading through a few answers there

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer!

```
SELECT a.*, b1.*
FROM table_A a
LEFT JOIN table_B b1 ON (a.id = b1.device_id)
LEFT JOIN table_B b2 ON (a.id = b2.device_id AND 
    (b1.date < b2.date OR b1.date = b2.date AND b1.id < b2.id))
WHERE b2.id IS NULL
ORDER BY a.id
```